# Sort and display items in a list randomly every time using pure static html(5)

Tags: html

I have a big list of products (10.000 unique items). I have them in a text file, I can produce them in any format (one per row, CSV, etc.)

I want to build a web page using static html or html5 (no javascript) that every time when loaded or refreshed will display in an ordered or un-ordered list randomly chosen 25 unique items out of a total of 10.000 (or round robin, etc.).

Is there any way I could do this? Thank you.

Comment: No, HTML has no scripting ability. You would need JavaScript at a minimum, or a server-side language.

Comment: Any particular reason for not using JavaScript of server side code?

Comment: How do you expect to load dynamic content to your static HTML files w/o some sort of scripting language? (i.e. JavaScript or other) - this is exactly the reason the scripting languages were brought into the mix, to allow dynamic content loaded onto the HTML pages.

Answer (score 2):

If you want absolutely no JavaScript(or any scripting), then the short answer is it is not possible.

HTML is a markup language and cannot perform such scripting tasks. Here is the W3C docs for html5 and its capabilities: [html5](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/)

Comment: @ochi I agree the goal is to promote good content/answers. The point of reputation thresholds is to prevent spam and bots. Otherwise answers would likely have a higher reputation threshold than comments as they are more prominently displayed on pages.